# local PHP & local node.js (react-native)

Tags: php, node.js, apache, react-native, localhost

I have a local Apache server using XAMPP which runs on port 80 and uses a local PHP file.

In the browser I can open this file from `localhost/test/test.php` and `localhost:80/test/test.php`.

I also have a react-native app, and it starts an NPM server on port 8081.

In this app I want to make a request to the local PHP file, but when I make the request it returns a 404 error. 
I understand that it happens because the NPM server doesn't know about the local Apache server so I want to understand how to combine them.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried with react-native.

Answer (score 0):

don't write 'localhost/test/test.php'
You have to write with your ip, like this => '192.16x.x.x/test.php/'